# In what time zone are R's file.info()'s mtime expressed?

Tags: r

I have a file for which Windows (win7) explorer says that its mtime is `24-oct-2014 12:39`. When I ask for this/these properties in R using `file.info()`, I am getting the following:

```
file.info('r:/data/dm29/dm29 - Sample_138_20141023_0737.dti')
                                                     size isdir mode               mtime               ctime               atime exe
r:/data/dm29/dm29 - Sample_138_20141023_0737.dti 35003850 FALSE  666 2014-10-24 11:39:48 2014-10-23 07:40:32 2014-11-06 11:14:49  no
```

What's going on here? I suppose it has something to do with time zones but I cannot find a reference to something like that in the help. Or is it perhaps due to a recent DST switch that we had?

Additionally, how can I fix it in an idiomatic way? The following feels a bit like a kludge to me.

```
mt <- as.POSIXct(file.info('r:/data/dm29/dm29 - Sample_138_20141023_0737.dti')$mtime, tz='Europe/London')
attributes(mt)$tzone <- 'Europe/Amsterdam'
```

Comment: I'm unclear as to why you expect the Windows display to agree with the R display? Does the Windows display correspond to your local time or to a different one? What about file.info's?

Comment: I am expecting that because given that R appears/is working in the same time zone, why would the two give different time stamps when the mtime is the same?